# jquery value from clicked object

Tags: jquery, object, click

Hello i have a few buttons generated with Jquery.
Now i would get the value only from the clicked button.

But how can i get the value i alway get a blank massage.
below you can see the relevant code.

Hope someone can help me.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var count=1;
    var nr=0;
    var pfad=[];
    $.ajax({
        method:"post",
        url:"phpcode.php",
        data:{func:"bilder"},
        success:function(data){
            var arr=[];
            images=data.split(";");
            länge=images.length;
            for(i=0;i<länge;i++){
                arr[i]=data.split(";")[i];
            }
            arr.pop();
            generate(arr);
        }
    });
    function generate(arr){
        länge=arr.length;
        for(i=0;i<länge;i++){
            if(i<1){
                $("main").append("<div value="+count+" class='pfade'><a>bild"+count+":</a><input name='bild' value="+arr[i]+" placeholder='pfad' type='text'/><button class='button' data-count="+count+" type='button'>X</button></div> ");
            count=count+1;
            }
            else{
                $("main").append("<div value="+count+" class='pfade'><a>bild"+count+":</a><input name='bild' value="+arr[i]+" placeholder='pfad' type='text'/><button class='button' data-count="+count+" type='button'>X</button></div> ");
                count=count+1;
            }
        }
    }

    $("#del").click(function(){
        val=count-1;
        $("div[value="+val+"]").remove();
        count=count-1;
    });

    $(document).on("click",".button",function(){
        val=$(this).attr("data-count");
        alert(val);
    });

    $("#more").click(function(){
       $("main").append("<div value="+count+" class='pfade'><a>bild"+count+":</a><input name='bild' value='' placeholder='pfad' type='text'/><button class='button' data-count="+count+" type='button'>X</button></div> ");
       count=count+1;
    }); 
    $("#sub").click(function(){
        var pfad=[];
        $("input[name='bild']").each(function(){
            if($(this).val()!= ""){
                pfad.push($(this).val());
            }
        });
        alert(pfad);
        $.ajax({
            url: "phpcode.php",
            method: "POST",
            data:{func:"addimg"},
            success:function(data){ 
            }
        });
    });
});
```

here is an image just forHere is a picture showing that the button actually has a value:
[button with value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWSx4.png)

Comment: of course but it would not help you because the button are generated in the Jquery code. `<main>    
            <div class="pfade">
                <input id="sub" type="submit">
            </div>
            <div class="pfade">
                <button id="more" type="button">hinzufügen</button>
            </div>
            <div class="pfade">
                <button id="del" type="button">löschen</button>
            </div>
        </main>`

Comment: where you are calling the `generate()` function.?

Comment: updated post above with the entire code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code apart from the fact that the button has not a value attribute. 
To get the text displayed by the button as a value you have to use:

```
val=$(this).text();
```

instead of:

```
val=$(this).val();
```

If you need to pass some other values via the button you have to use the data-* attributes.
So change `value=` in your button with `data-count=`

```
<button class='button' data-count="+count+" type='button'>X</button>
```

and then retrieve the value with:

```
val=$(this).attr('data-count');
```

Your code works for form elements that support the value attribute.

Comment: thank you that's exactly what I need. I did not know that a button not supports the value attribute.

Comment: Change $(this).attr('data-count') to $(this).data('count') for better scalability.

Comment: Yes. This is even better